# JSON from php MySQL-query showing non-existent columns

Tags: php, mysql, json, xampp

Alright, so what I have is a very simple XAMPP setup with a database containing a single table with two rows. I have a php script that grabs one of these rows at random and then prints the resulting query in JSON. For whatever reason though the JSON has 'columns' (don't really want to call them columns because JSON can't have columns but, yeah..) that don't actually exist in the table.

I'm pretty new to everything in the XAMPP stack so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Here's my table:

[image]

Here's the resulting JSON:

```
{"0":"1","id":"0.9645465863538408","1":"Big Mac","name":"Big Mac","2":"A double layer of sear-sizzled 100% pure beef mingled with special sauce on a sesame seed bun and topped with melty American cheese, crisp lettuce, minced onions and tangy pickles.","description":"A double layer of sear-sizzled 100% pure beef mingled with special sauce on a sesame seed bun and topped with melty American cheese, crisp lettuce, minced onions and tangy pickles.","3":"http:\/\/www.mcdonalds.com\/content\/dam\/McDonalds\/item\/mcdonalds-Big-Mac.png","imgSrc":"http:\/\/www.mcdonalds.com\/content\/dam\/McDonalds\/item\/mcdonalds-Big-Mac.png","4":"2","upVotes":"2","5":"1","downVotes":"1","6":"0.9645465863538408"}
```

("0", "1", etc. don't exist in the table)

here's my php:

```
$password = "";
$usertable = "mcdonalds"; 

//Connect
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to 
connect to $hostname . Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetch
$query = "SELECT * FROM `McDonalds`AS r1 JOIN(SELECT (RAND() *(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `McDonalds`)) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id  ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
//Print
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: First, you mean `columns`, not `rows`.  Second, have you `var_dumped` the $row? It's an array, with indexes.  And third, no comment about this question would be complete without pointing out that `mysql` is deprecated, insecure, and should be replaced with `mysql` or `PDO`

Comment: @cale_b means `mysqli`* or `PDO` :)

Comment: ...and, can you explain what you're trying to achieve with that SQL query?

Comment: I bet it is your join causing that to show up. Specify the columns you want in your select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. By default, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array with both named and numeric indexes for each column.

Or you could use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`. The default second argument is `MYSQL_BOTH`, which causes the result you see.

Comment: that's it. didn't realize that it would print both names and numbers of indexes.

Comment: It just prints whatever is in the array. If there are two indexes, it prints them both.